# SOLR Ping Request is causing Exception

Tags: solr

We are using Solr 3.5 and having the issue related to Ping Solr.

This is what defined in SolrConfig.xml for Ping

```
<!-- ping/healthcheck -->
  <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

There is no mention about text here but still we are getting this error HTTP Status 500 - Ping query caused exception: undefined field text org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Ping query caused exception: undefined field text at org.apache.solr.handler.PingRequestHandler.handleRequestBody(PingRequestHandler.java:76) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376) at

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Amitesh

Comment: Got it working after replacing the "text" with "title" in solrconfig.xml file.

Comment: I cannot see text in your ping request handler. Where exactly did you change text to title? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

You can modify it like this:

```xml
  <!-- ping/healthcheck -->
  <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
      <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
      <str name="df">a field that is defined in your schema</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```